# How to modify Hash to enable access of element 'hash[:a][:b]' by shorter 'hash[:a,:b]' in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash, indexing

I would be happy to access any element of multi-dimensional hash-array by a shorter expression

```
h = {a: {b: 'c'}}

# default way
p h[:a][:b] # => "c"

# a nicer way
p h[:a,:b] # => "c"

# nice assignment
h[:a,:b] = 1
p h # => {:a=>{:b=>1}}
```

I realize that in this way one eliminates the possibility to have a hash key being an array.

```
{[:a,:b] => "c"}
```

Since it is quite rare situation, I would prefer to reduce number of [] in my expressions.

How can one achieve this?

---

**Update**

Ok, I wasn't clear. The problem is that I have tried to make custom `[]` and `[]=` methods myself, but failed. Could you show me how such functionality can be implemented?

**Multi-dimensional arrays**

If you are looking for something similar for arrays, have a look on `narray` gem http://narray.rubyforge.org/

```
>> a = NArray.int(5,5)
=> NArrayint5,5: 
[ [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ], 
  [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ], 
  [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ], 
  [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ], 
  [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ] ]
>> a[1,2]
=> 0
>> a[1,2]=1
=> 1
>> a
=> NArrayint5,5: 
[ [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ], 
  [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ], 
  [ 0, 1, 0, 0, 0 ], 
  [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ], 
  [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ] ]
>> a[1,0..4]=1
=> 1
>> a
=> NArrayint5,5: 
[ [ 0, 1, 0, 0, 0 ], 
  [ 0, 1, 0, 0, 0 ], 
  [ 0, 1, 0, 0, 0 ], 
  [ 0, 1, 0, 0, 0 ], 
  [ 0, 1, 0, 0, 0 ] ]
```

Comment: I would just use all the []s required. You'd confuse the hell out of anyone else looking at your code otherwise.

Comment: OK, I promise to keep this code for myself only, or to provide clear comments every time I use it. :)

Comment: @DanSingerman I wish there were bounties for comments. Yes. A thousand times yes.

@Andrei Please don't redefine such a basic aspect of the language's syntax for the sake of an (arguably) "nicer" looking lookup. Anyone you work with (and you yourself in a few months) is only going to be thrown off.

Comment: :) I understand your point very well. But don't worry, I will not show it to anyone except here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have fixed my code, so now it works

```
class AutoHash < Hash
  def initialize *args
    super
    @update, @update_index = args[0][:update], args[0][:update_key] unless 
args.empty?
  end

    def [] key,*args
      if args.count > 0
        self[key][*args]
      else
        if self.has_key? key
          super key
        else
          AutoHash.new :update => self, :update_key => key
        end
      end
    end

    def []= *args
      v = args.pop
      k = args.shift
      if args.count > 0
        self[k][*args]= v
      else
        @update[@update_index] = self if @update and @update_index
        super k,v
      end
    end
end
```

Examples

```
a = AutoHash.new
a[:a][:b][:c] = 123
a[:a,:b,:c] = 321
p a # => {:a=>{:b=>{:c=>321}}}
```

If such definition is too confusing, then one could name the method differently (e.g. `#path` instead of redifining `[]`)

```
h[:a][:b][:c] = 123
p h.path(:a,:b,:c) # => 123

h.path(:a,:b,:c)= 321
p h #=> {:a=>{:b=>{:c=>321}}}

mypath = [:a,:b,:c]
p h.path(mypath) #=> 321
```

Comment: There is a little typo:

h.path(:a,:b:,:c)= 321 should be h.path(:a, :b, :c) = 321

Answer (score 1):

If you really want something like this then Ruby allows you to implement custom versions of `[]` and `[]=` on classes of your choice including the Hash class provided by the language. Use with care if modifying base classes